# How to use a specific (not default) jar from maven central repo with maven? (hive-exec)

Tags: java, maven, hive

The `hive-exec` module evilly use a fatjar for maven import, which causes buckets of class dependency error like `guava`, `protobuf`, `parquet`, etc. I imported it like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But i found a jar named `hive-exec-3.1.2-core.jar` in [hive-exec maven repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-exec/3.1.2/), which just contains its own classes!

Is there any elegant way to import this jar file with maven as my dependecy instead of the default fatjar?

Or if it's unreachable, literally what's the meaning of putting that jar there?

*P.S. I know maven-shading it in another module can solve my problem, but is there actually a way to solve it in place without create another module.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it in this way:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    <classifier>core</classifier>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

whether this is a proper replacement, I cannot say.